# Oracle GROUP BY giving error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

let's assume we have two tables

```
table1
    ----------------------
    |ID         | Date   |
    ----------------------
    |1          |20110101|
    |1          |20110102|
    |1          |20110103|
    |2          |20110102|
    |2          |20110103|
    |2          |20110104|
    ----------------------

table2
    ----------------------
    |ID2        |val     |
    ----------------------
    |1          |152     |
    |2          |155     |
    ----------------------
```

Using this query

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID2
GROUP BY table1.ID 
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Mysql should return this

```
-------------------------------------------
|ID         |date    |ID2        |val     |
-------------------------------------------
|1          |20110103|1          |152     |
|2          |20110104|2          |155     |
-------------------------------------------
```

In Oracle I get this error:
`ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

EDIT:
The `MAX` function on the column `Date` does not work because this column is `varchar(200)` 
The database/tables structure is not mine and I cannot alter it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID2` ?

Comment: Yeah sorry I forget to write it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one of two things...

- GROUP BY and use aggregate functions to consolidate multiple records down to one
- Use some lookup to identify the one record you want from the group

In your case, you don't just want a MAX() from table1, as it *may* be possible that a higher `id` has a lower `date`.  In that case, I'd be inclined to use a lookup system...

```
WITH
  ordered_table1 AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_field DESC) AS sequence_number,
    *
  FROM
    table1
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ordered_table1
INNER JOIN
  table2
    ON table2.id = ordered_table1.id
WHERE
  ordered_table1.sequence_id = 1
```

**NOTE:**  This assumes your date is formatted such that alphanumeric ordering WILL yield the correct date order.  If that is NOT the case (and `d-m-yyyy` will ***not*** order correctly), you need to replace `date_field` with `TO_DATE(date_field)` to ensure the correct order.

**NOTE:** Use of `TO_DATE(date_field)` will also probably fix your MAX() problems.

**NOTE:** If you want to store dates as strings, but them to be order friendly, use `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Wouldn't using a DISTINCT ID, MAX(date) select with a group by ID eliminate the need for the row_number?

Comment: The OP has stated tat MAX(date) won't work as the date field is a string in the format `d-m-yyyy`.  As per my second **NOTE:**, this means that MAX(`TO_DATE(date_field)`) is needed to make it work.  At that point, the DISTINCT is also no longer needed.  The benefit of ROW_NUMBER(), however, is that it is more generalised - If there are other un-ordered fields in table1, this will still find them.  If the real-life case does actually only have `id` and `date` fields then yes using `MAX(TO_DATE(date))` is sufficient when used with `GROUP BY table1.id, table2.id2, table2.val`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it in following way:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
       ON table1.ID = table2.ID
 ORDER BY DATE DESC
 GROUP BY table1.ID
```

Comment: it works but it returned me multiple rows for the same ID, I only want 1 row for ID..

Comment: MySQL will allow the lack of aggregate functions here, ORACLE will not.  You have a GROUP BY after an ORDER by which won't compile.  Other than using `JOIN` instead of `,` (and JOIN is a whole bunch better, thank you!) the query is not almost identical to what the OP tried to get the error message.

Comment: Ok - I remember one case that I had to specify fields I group by in `SELECT` statement. What about `SELECT table1.ID, table1.Date, table2.ID2, table2.val FROM ....` ?

Comment: The OP needs one record from table1 for each record in table2.  Thus your use of `GROUP BY` (as well as the OP's).  This will lead to multiple values in the `date` field, and thus need an aggregate function over that field.  The OP has stated, however, that `MAX()` can't be used as the field is a string.  This means that `MAX(TO_DATE(date_field))` is need for your solution to work.

Comment: Oh, AND the GROUP BY should be expanded to `GROUP BY table1.id, table2.id2, table2.val`

Answer (score 1):

In the select and order by clause of a SQL Statement with group by you can only use the columns/expression used in the group by or aggregate functions (min, max, avg ..) of other columns.

I know this for oracle and I am a little surprised that this is different in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Group by in oracle implies that you are trying to run an aggregate function (sum, count, etc.) on one of the columns.  It appears that you are just looking to order by ID first and then the date.  I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1
       JOIN table2 ON (table1.ID = table2.ID2)
ORDER BY ID,
         DATE DESC
```

If that is not what you are intending, then the answer is that you need each column in the select clause that is not part of an aggregate function to be in the group clause.

**EDIT**

In response to the comment:

It's probably best to filter table 1 down first as a subquery and then join to table2:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ID,MAX(TO_DATE(DATE,'mm-dd-yyyy')) FROM Table1 GROUP BY ID) T1
       JOIN Table2 ON (T1.ID = Table2.ID2)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Yeah, but this way I got multiple rows for the same ID, because and ID can have multiple 'date'.. I only want 1 row for ID, so using MYSQL I used group by that returned my only 1 record

Comment: @Marcx - Your comment confuses me, are you using MySQL or ORACLE?  They behave differently, allow different syntax, and have different operators available to them...

Comment: I'm using Oracle. The date column is varchar so I cannot use max()

Comment: This answer has `MAX(TO_DATE(date))`.  Using TO_DATE() should allow MAX() to behave as you desire it to.

Comment: using `SELECT DISTINCT ID,MAX(TO_DATE(DATE,'YYYYMMDD')) FROM table1` return me a `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`, btw the MAX(TO_DATE()) function works great unless I don't select the ID...

Comment: @Marcx - Did you copy the query in the answer?  There is a sub-query that uses `MAX(TO_DATE())`, and that sub-query has a `GROUP BY`.  If you are struggling to make an aggregate function work, or struggling when using GROUP BY, I'd suggest reading the manual on `GROUP BY` to understand how it behaves.

Comment: Don't use ` SELECT DISTINCT` in combination with `GROUP BY`. The point of grouping is to give you distinct values, so an explicit `SELECT DISTINCT` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In general, saying `select * from` in combination with `group by` is a bad idea. The expressions in the select clause need to be scalar, that is, either aggregate functions of the group, or unrelated to the grouping, or in the group by clause themselves. `Select *` pretty much guarantees that that will not be the case. You probably want something like this instead:

```
select t1.id, max(t1.date), t2.id, max(t2.val)
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
  group by t1.id
  order by  max(t1.date) desc
```

Comment: why would you ever make a date column a varchar? In any case, to create an output like the one you want, you need some sort of aggregate function which tells the database which of the date values to take.