# How to group rows in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table

```
___________________
Column 1 | Column 2
-------------------
    30   |     1
    30   |     2
    30   |     3
    31   |     1
    31   |     2
    31   |     3
    32   |     1
    32   |     2
    32   |     3
    ...
```

I want the resulting set to be

```
   ___________________
   Column 1 | Column 2
   -------------------
       30   |     x (doesn't matter which one)
       31   |     x (doesn't matter which one)
       32   |     x (doesn't matter which one)
```

The reason why column 2 doesn't really matter is beacuse columns 3-10 (which I excluded) are exactly the same for all rows where the value in column 1 is the same.

I've tried a plethora of different queries in the Oracle DB, but nothing seems to be working.

I tried:

```
 SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM table GROUP BY Column1
```

But as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901522/oracle-group-by-giving-error-ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression?rq=1), that's not how the GROUP BY clause works in Oracle.

I've also tried `SELECT DISTINCT` but this hasn't worked either.

How should I go about doing this? The main gotcha is that the GROUP BY here doesn't behave the same way as it does in MySQL, which I'm familiar with.

Comment: Have you tried simply `select column1, min(column2) from yourTable group by column1`?

Comment: This question is so old; how did you know i was editing it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care which, just use `MAX()` or `MIN()`:

```
SELECT Column1, MIN(Column2)
FROM table
GROUP BY Column1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an aggregate function:

```
SELECT Column1, max(Column2) FROM table GROUP BY Column1
```

The above returns the highest (you can also use min or avg or any other agg function)

Or you can show all the values with LISTAGG:

```
SELECT Column1,
       listagg(Column2, ', ') within group(order by column2) as col2vals
  FROM table
 GROUP BY Column1
```

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with Oracle... but, am I right to think that `listagg()` works in a similar fashion as MySQL's `group_concat()`?

Comment: Yes, the syntax is different but is functionally equivalent. However in Oracle you cannot use DISTINCT with LISTAGG, where in MySQL you can use DISTINCT with group_concat

Answer (score 0):

if x output doesn't matter

```
select 
   Column1,
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, Column2 || ' | ')).extract ('//text()'), ' | ') Column2
from 
   [table_name]
group by 
   Column1
;
```